Guess the famous movie line: rm -rf / --no-preserve-root
Here's another Linux command representing a famous movie line:

$ rm -rf / --no-preserve-root

Which line is it?

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Perhaps this should come with the don't-try-this-at-home tag?

"Here's another Linux command" -- implying there has already been other examples like this?

Certainly do not try at work as sysadmin. One perhaps striking detail is the $ prompt which indicates user as opposed to # indicating root. I do not have the courage to try it out as user :(.

@BenjaminWang Perhaps referring to this popular question?

@FirstNameLastName also do not try it as a user. it won't delete things it can't, but that won't stop it from deleting anything you're allowed to.

After command finishes:

 There's no place like home :
 The Wizard of Oz (1939)


 alluding to home directories which are removed everywhere

as commented in OP

 not sure what effect this has as user $ versus sysadmin # ... it might delete user home ... I have no intention to verify (certainly not after previous sudo access)


Then the command would use something other than / presumably. Like (if this works) /*/home/.

@msh210 ; home directories can be anywhere. Placing them in /home is a good convention but not mandatory. Also, Linux root home directory often is /root but also not required to be there.


 Some men just want to watch the world burn.


Please [edit] to explain why this answer fits the question
